# AWS S3 Bucket - Access Denied when trying to upload a file

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a File to AWS S3 amazon from an HTTP request in my frontend app but I'm receiving the following error in my browser: 
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://my-bucket.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/08…nedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, …}
In the Network tab it shows: "Access Denied" Error

So, I think there is an issue with the Policy of my bucket:
  This is what I've configured in my bucket Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1544564620007",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1544564832145",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<account-number>:root"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
    }
]
```

}

Also, The CORS configuration of the bucket is the following:

```
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I'm using ASW SDK in my backend server (node.js using express) to get my signed URL:

```
     var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    .....
    app.post('/requestUploadURL', function(request, response) {
     var s3 = new AWS.S3(
        {accessKeyId: "<my AWS Access Key Id here>",
         secretAccessKey: "<my AWS Secret Key here>",
         endpoint: 's3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com',
         signatureVersion: 'v4',
         region: 'sa-east-1'} 
       );

    var params = request.body;

    var s3Params = {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket', 
      Key:  params.name, //file name
      ContentType: params.type, // file type
      ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    var uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);

    response.status(200).json({
         uploadURL: uploadURL
      })
 }
```

And in my front end app (vue.js) I have this code to upload the file using the pre-signed URL obtained from my backend:

```
  ...
 submitFile(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener('loadend', function(e) {
     axios.post("http://localhost:3000/requestUploadURL", {
          name: file.name,
          type: file.type
      }) // end Api().post
     .then(response => {
        console.log('Upload file to AWS ')
        console.log(response)
        console.log(reader)
        var url = response.data.uploadURL
        fetch(url, {
           method: 'PUT',
           body: new Blob([reader.result], {type: file.type})
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('Uploaded successfull ')
            console.log(res)
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Upload error: ')
            console.log(error)
          })
      }) // end first .then(response =>
   }) // end reader.addEventListener

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return false
 } // end submit
```

I've to open Chorme using --args --disable-web-security because since I'm running locally the front end app (localhost:8081) and also the backend (localhost:3000). If not Chrome didn't allow to send the HTTP request due to CORS issue.

So, please take in account I'm running this locally, and I'm using my root AWS account KEY and Secret KEY in my backend to set up the backend express servers (for getting the signed URL). I'm not using USER's (IAM)

Do you know what could be my issue? I'm setting up the Bucket Policy wrongly? Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: A pre-signed URL does not require/use a bucket policy. Instead, it will use the permissions of the IAM User that created the signature. What permissions are assigned to the entity that signed the URL? If you are using root credentials to create the signed URL, this is not a good idea. Generally, try to avoid using root credentials. Instead, create an IAM User for the application, or even just for the signing part of the application.

Comment: Yes, I was using the root credentials because I was not able to make it work with an user. So, now I've tried again to create an IAM User (called 'tester') and used those credentials to get the pre-signed URL in my backend (express server). When creating this user, I've followed this steps:
1. checked option 'Programmatic access'
2. then clicked on 'Attach existing policies directly'
3. selected: 'AmazonS3FullAccess'
4. Next - add permission...

Comment: Finally, i got back to the backend and replaced the Access Key ID and Secret Ket ID by this user's credentials and tried again.. but the same issue occurs. Am I doing something wrong? The upload request is being sent from the front end (vue.js app) and it's using the pre-signed URL like I'm showing in the code above. thanks for any help!

Comment: just solved... the problem was that the bucket has not public access and the CORS policy needed to have the local domain set up to:   <AllowedOrigin> http://localhost/8080</AllowedOrigin> and removed the others which were wrong since this bucket does not allow anonymous users to access. AND also updated the S3params in my backend replacing the line  ACL: 'public-read' to 'private;'.... because the bucket does not allow to upload public files since it's not public...

Comment: I also removed the policy in the bucket like you suggested and created the user with S3 full access and set up my backend with its credentials in order to get the pre-signed URL! thanks so much!!!!